# How I can match bags an passenger in the reclaim area?

Tags: anylogic

I'm simulating a security control process, and i can't do that each passenger pickup their baggage. I have tried with Match, Combine, Pickup, but I still can't execute the commands correctly.

I've created the follow flowchart, and the problem is in the wReclaimPax, pickup and wReclaimBags blocks (you can see them in the picture).
https://ibb.co/v3V57Tm

I saw this link [Anylogic - Combined multiple items back to original owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54729083/anylogic-combined-multiple-items-back-to-original-owner?answertab=active#tab-top) to understand something, but I still need help.

I've created 3 functions:

isMatch:

```
if(equipaje.pasajeroLink.equals(pasajero.equipajeLink)){
  return true;
}
return false;
```

paxBags:

```
for(int i=0;i<wait.size();i++){
   Pasajero p=(Pasajero)wait.get(i);
   if(isMatch(p,bag))
     return p;
}
return null;
```

bagsPax:

```
for(int i=0;i<wait.size();i++){
   Equipaje e=(Equipaje)wait.get(i);
   if(isMatch(pasajero,e))
     return e;
}

return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Assumed context

You haven't really explained how your code is related to your process but I'm assuming the following:

1. Because this is luggage-retrieval, you want to ensure that a passenger
   agent (Pasajero) only enters the Pickup block (representing taking bag from
   carousel) when his bag (Equipaje agent by the look of it) has
   arrived into the `wReclaimBag` Wait, and been released from it to
   `queue4` Queue.
2. For this you need triggers (to remove agents from Wait blocks) when
   *either* a passenger (Pasajero) arrives in `wReclaimPax` Wait, or a bag (Equipaje) arrives
   in the `wReclaimBag` Wait (because you don't know whether the passenger or their bag will get to their respective Wait blocks first).

So your `paxBags` function is called in on-entry action of the `wReclaimBag` Wait, and your `bagsPax` function in the on-entry action of the `wReclaimPax` Wait.

## Possible problems with current approach

Without knowing more of your model it's hard to say but problems I can think of based on what you've supplied are:

- Your functions return the Pasajero or Equipaje if there is one that matches. Your match check relies seemingly on bidirectional connections (links) between Pasajero and Equipaje. Obviously if they're not setup properly the model won't work and, if you're using bidirectional connections you shouldn't need to check both ends.
- Your functions need calling so that, if they return non null, they then free the matching agent from the other Wait block, *and* free themselves. Are you doing that? Without checking, there may be issues with calling `free` for yourself as you enter a Wait block (since this kind of depends on AnyLogic internals as to whether you count as being 'in' the block at this stage and can be freed). If this seems to be the problem you could create a timeout 0 dynamic event instance to do the free so that you're not doing it within the scope of the on-enter action.
- Your pickup block (since it's been setup so that the entering agent will always want to pickup the first agent (Equipaje) in `queue4`) just needs to be set as waiting for quantity 1 (though see below).
- If you've done all this the most likely problem is that the underlying events ordering of AnyLogic is affecting things. When you free agents I'm fairly sure the freeing actually happens in a timeout 0 event scheduled under-the-covers. So it may be that the passenger arrives at the Pickup *before* their Equipment arrives in `queue4` though, if you set the Pickup to be "Exact quantity (wait for)", with quantity of 1, it should handle that.

The animation of the process (numbers in/out/within each block and details when clicking on blocks) should also help you debug what is going wrong; e.g., are bags being left in the Wait when they should have been released, etc.

P.S. With this kind of thing you should always create a minimal example model to make testing the issue/solution easier (and for sharing in help forums such as this where the rest of the complexity of your model is irrelevant). Often you find the problem 'naturally' in the process of trying to construct such a model that reproduces your problem in a minimal way.