# agents stuck in the delay block - anylgoic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I checked all parameters/options in the delay time block (time unit, delay time, ...etc) all are fine, same for seize block

- screenshot of the problem (2 resources units are used in seize resourcePool, and 1 min in the delay block:
  [image]
- screenshot after relaxing the number of resources in the seize resourcePool to 3000 units (just any big number), and 1 min in the daily block (the same delay time not changed):
  [image]

I have many seize, delay, and release blocks before this (Before the Drug Delivery) all are working fine. The 2882 agents are reaching the Drug Delivery blocks at the expected time, however, they are stuck there.

Sorry I can not share the model itself.

- working hours of DrugDelivery resources have already been checked and they are fine
- No other blocks are using the DrugDelivery resources
- Maximum capacity of the delay_DrugDeivery block is enabled/on
- Maximum capacity of the seize_DrugDeliverers block is enabled/on
- I tried to delete these blocks, but when doing that the flow of agent is coprated, no errors but no flow
- What else?

Answer (score 1):

what happens here is that after the release block, there is something that is not allowing your agents to flow. This could be a queue, a hold, impossible to know since you don't share

You will see that if you use in the delay block in the advanced section "force pushing" you will get an error because your agent has nowhere to go

Comment: Thank you Felipe, yes I did this and found that the combine block after the release was not allowing agents to flow because they should be combined in order FCFS or something like this. For your kind reference,  I followed your answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54729083/anylogic-combined-multiple-items-back-to-original-owner) and added wait blocks, then I figure out how to check if all connected agents arrived to wait blocks to free them (please see me answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72502795/check-if-agent-connected-to-an-agent-is-on-the-wait-block-anylogic)