# Check if agent connected to an agent is on the wait block - anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

**Direct question: how to check if an agent is waiting in the wait block?**

More details? below, thank you.

---

I was following Mr. Felipe's answer to a similar question (this one: [Anylogic - Combined multiple items back to original owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54729083/anylogic-combined-multiple-items-back-to-original-owner) )

On step number 4 of his answer, he said " *On the passengerWait, on the onEnter action you will check if all the bags connected to the passenger are on the bagWait block... if they are... then you will free (wait.free(agent)) the passenger and the bags* "

Do you know how to check this? I have the same problem between single patient and single drug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do that:

1. Make a new variable in the Passenger agent and call it
   `variable_IsWaitingForBag`
2. Make a new variable in the Bag agent and call it `variable_IsWaitingForPassenger`
3. In `onEnter` of `passengerWait`, use the following:

   ```
   if(agent.agentLink_myBag.getConnectedAgent().variable_IsWaitingForPassenger)
   {
   passengerWait.free(agent);
   bagWait.free(agent.agentLink_myPassenger.getConnectedAgent());
   }
   agent.variable_IsWaitingForBag=true;
   ```
4. Do the opposite in `onEnter` of the `bagWait` block

Comment: I corrected the if statement it should be:
if(agent.agentLink_myBag.getConnectedAgent().variable_IsWaitingForPassenger)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid going into the details of your model and naming of blocks, I will provide you with something generic that should help you achieve what you need.

1. The first step is to know how to iterate through the agents inside the wait block. To do that, you need a for loop with the syntax shown in the code below. (Replace `Agent` with the agent type of agents in the wait block, replace `waitBlock` with you wait block's name.)
2. The character `a` now refers to the agent in the wait block being evaluated in each iteration.
3. Now, you just add your condition where you check if any of the agents in the wait block match your condition which is whether they are equal to whichever connected agent to the one going through the wait block.

   ```
   Agent x = null;
   for( Agent a : waitBlock ) {

      if( a.equals(agent.agentLink.getConnectedAgent()) ) {

         x = a ;
         break;
      }
   }

   if( x != null ) {
      waitBlock.free( x );
   }
   ```

Another simplified code would be:

```
Agent x = findFirst( waitBlock , a -> a.equals(agent.agentLink.getConnectedAgent()) );
   if( x != null ) {    
   waitBlock.free(x);    
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Emile, maybe my problem was simpler than this. Please see my answer. Thank you.

Comment: this code will throw likely a concurrentmodificationexception you are looping through a collection that is being modified.... also it should be a.equals(agent.agentLink.getConnectedAgent())

Comment: Code corrected. I think now it should address the issue you mentioned.